# Show product attribute on product page magento 2.4

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4, magento-product-attributes

i need to show an attribute to product page under the name of the product. The attribute is text and the code is plustile

I try to load it to a shopbybrand extension that has a block in the wanted area with the code

```
<?php
// check attribute exists (Where 'dimension' is the attribute code for your attribute)
if ($attribute = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('flooring_width')): ?>
    <?php
    // get label for the current store (in case you have multiple stores and languages)
    $_attribute_label = $attribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName());
    // get the attribute value (for other attributes change getDimension to getName where name is the name of your attribute );
    $_attribute_value = $this->getProduct()->getFlooringWidth();
    ?>
    <?php
    // check there is a value for the attribute
    if (isset($_attribute_value)): ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $_attribute_label . ': ' . $_attribute_value; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$attrData = $_product->getData('plustitle');
$blockTitle = $this->getData('title');
if (trim($attrData) !== "") : ?>
    <div class="product-full-width-section">
        <h2 class="product-section-title"><?= $blockTitle; ?></h2>
        <?php echo $attrData; ?>
        <?php echo 'mplampla';?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i get
Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in

i try to make an extension  like
https://www.dckap.com/blog/display-custom-attribute-value-product-viewlist-page-magento-2/

but with no success

Can you advise for the correct way to do it or
Do you know any extension to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

first added this code on your phtml and then use the product object :

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();

if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: It don't run anything after 
```
if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: my full code i try to run is 
```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();

if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}

$attrData = $_product->getData('plustitle');
$blockTitle = $this->getData('title');
if (trim($attrData) !== "") : ?>
    <div class="product-full-width-section">
        <h2 class="product-section-title"><?= $blockTitle; ?></h2>
        <?php echo $attrData; ?>
  <?php echo 'mplampla';?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get product data from your block i.e. $block->getProduct

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with replacing the

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

with

```
$_product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class)->registry('product');
```